# Implement a long running process in windows store app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, backgroundworker

I need to run a background process which gonna poll on a web service every 5 minutes.
I want this process to start on app startup and runs forever.

In Android I can use a Service for this kind of situation but I don't know how to approach this
on windows store apps.(Windows 8.1)

Comment: It's helpful to clarify your question with the scenario you're trying to implement. As Damir noted, the shortest time for a background time trigger is 15-30 minutes. If you're trying to do a tile update, you can tell Windows to make the request for you and no background task is needed. If you're trying to get more frequent data, then push notifications might be appropriate. So tell us what you're trying to accomplish, specifically.

Comment: I need to bring latest data from server to the app. It's a data sync between the app and the backend.

Comment: I don't need to do any tile update though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinRT apps you can use [background tasks with time triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx) to achieve a similar functionality. You won't be able to poll the web service every 5 minutes, though:

- In Windows 8, the minimum interval is 15 minutes; your app must also be pinned to the lock screen for them to be available.
- On Windows Phone the minimum interval is 30 minutes; there are no additional requirements.

You might also want to take a look at [push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761462.aspx) as an alternative approach to polling.